# How to create a sphere in css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms, shapes

I have trying to create a 3D sphere using just pure css, but I've been unable to generate the shape required. I've seen a [cylinder](http://jsfiddle.net/bmouxLwu/9/) but I can't find any reference to creating an actual *sphere*.

My current code looks like:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sphere {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 500%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5%;
}
.sphere::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  content: '';
  height: 45%;
  width: 12%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="sphere red"></div>
<div class="sphere green"></div>
<div class="sphere blue"></div>
<div class="sphere yellow"></div>
<div class="sphere"></div>
```

however,

- A: these are just 2D circles, not 3D shapes
- B: I can't rotate these in 3d (I want to have a spinning image) similar to that of a globe.

Sorry if i missed anything, but I'm not too sure where I should go to ask this.

Comment: `I can't find any reference to creating an actual sphere.`  [Really?](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&es_sm=122&q=how+to+create+a+sphere+in+css&oq=how+to+create+a+sphere+in+css)

Comment: Try to have a look at this: http://paulrhayes.com/experiments/sphere/

Comment: you might want to start with something smaller. have you tried making a cube first of all? a Sphere would take some time to create for this. Alternatively, yo9u could have a look at [this](http://codepen.io/akhil/pen/feLIu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below answer **is not an actual 3D shape**. It only gives a slight illusion of being 3D, however, depending on your use case, you may be able to 'fake' it:

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#222;}
div{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
    border-radius:50%;
    animation:spin 3s linear infinite;
    transform:rotate(-15deg);
    position:relative;
}
div:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-50px;
    border-radius:50%;
    left:0;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    transform:rotate(15deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    
}
div:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;z-index:12;
    top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:50%;
box-shadow:inset -20px -20px 20px 2px #222, inset 20px 20px 20px 5px rgba(200,200,200,0.4);    
}
@keyframes spin{
    to{background-position:-300px 0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

It's animating the `background-position` of the div, and by using box shadows, you could 'mimic' the shadowing of a 3D shape.

Comment: this looks really promising. Thanks!

Comment: I gott it using this! I didn't like the many elements from the links, though!

Answer (score 9):

**You might want to use 3D rotated circles**:

This uses rotated circles to look like a spherical grid. the lesser no. of elements, the better performance.

Some elements have been rotated in X axis, and others in Y axis. I have filled different colours to show this:

```css
#cont {
  perspective: 10000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: rotat 1s linear infinite;
  animation: rotat 10s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 50%;
}
.circ {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: orange;
}
.circ:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateX(120deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateX(150deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
/*other side rotated*/

.circ:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotateY(150deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(13) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.oth {
  background: crimson;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotat {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotat {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <!--rotated other side-->
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
</div>
```

You can also rotate some elements in Z direction, but that will make it even more buggy. Now **if you fill the same colours in circles, it almost looks like a sphere**:

```css
#cont {
  perspective: 10000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: rotat 1s linear infinite;
  animation: rotat 10s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 50%;
}
.circ {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: crimson;
}
.circ:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateX(120deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateX(150deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
/*other side rotated*/

.circ:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotateY(150deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(13) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.o {
  border: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotat {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotat {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <!--rotated other side-->
  <div class="circ o"></div>
  <div class="circ o"></div>
  <div class="circ o"></div>
  <div class="circ o"></div>
  <div class="circ o"></div>
  <div class="circ o"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I use JavaScript to build the sphere which formed by many div elements. To maintain the browser performance, the div elements are made as little as possible.

```js
var DIAMETER = 200;
var CELLS_PER_CIRCLE = 26;
var IMG_CELL = 'https://sites.google.com/site/zulnasibu/sphere/earth.png';
var NAME = 'sphere';
var WRAP = NAME + '-wrapper';
var _cssRules = '';
var _cellW;
var _cellAmount = 0;
var _imgW;
var _imgH;

function createFace(w, h, rx, ry, tz, ts, tsx, tsy, cname) {
 var face = document.createElement("div");
 var css;
 var cssText =
  'width: ' + w.toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'height: ' + h.toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'margin-left: ' + (-w / 2).toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'margin-top: ' + (-h / 2).toFixed(2) + 'px;' +
  'background: url("' + ts + '") ' + tsx.toFixed(2) + 'px ' + tsy.toFixed(2) + 'px;';
 css = 'transform: rotateY(' + ry.toFixed(2) + 'rad) rotateX(' + rx.toFixed(2) + 'rad) translateZ(' + tz.toFixed(2) + 'px);';
 cssText += addVendorPrefix(css);
 face.className = cname;
 face.style.cssText = cssText;
 return face;
}

function createModel() {
 var wrap = document.createElement("div");
 var model = document.createElement("div");
 wrap.className = WRAP;
 model.className = NAME;
 if (CELLS_PER_CIRCLE % 2 != 0) CELLS_PER_CIRCLE++;
 if (CELLS_PER_CIRCLE < 4) CELLS_PER_CIRCLE = 4;
 var baseAngle = Math.PI / CELLS_PER_CIRCLE;
 var cellAngle = 2 * baseAngle;
 _cellW = DIAMETER * Math.tan(baseAngle);
 _imgW = _cellW * CELLS_PER_CIRCLE;
 _imgH = CELLS_PER_CIRCLE / 2;
 if (CELLS_PER_CIRCLE % 4 == 0) _imgH++;
 _imgH *= _cellW;
 var xc = Math.ceil(CELLS_PER_CIRCLE / -4);
 var yc, rx, ry, tx, ty = -_imgH, tw, cang, cdia, cw;
 for (var x = xc; x <= -xc; x++) {
  rx = x * cellAngle;
  cw = _cellW;
  yc = CELLS_PER_CIRCLE;
  if (Math.abs(rx) == Math.PI / 2)
   yc = 1;
  else if (Math.abs(x) != 1) {
   cang = rx - Math.sign(x) * cellAngle / 2;
   cdia = DIAMETER * Math.cos(cang);
   cw = cdia * Math.tan(baseAngle);
  }
  _cellAmount += yc;
  tw = cw * yc;
  tx = (tw - _imgW) / 2;
  ty += _cellW;
  for (var y = 0; y < yc; y++) {
   ry = y * cellAngle;
   model.appendChild(createFace(cw + 1, _cellW + 1, rx, ry, DIAMETER / 2, IMG_CELL, tx, ty, 'cell' + x.toString() + y.toString()));
   tx -= cw;
  }
 }
 wrap.appendChild(model);
 var style = document.createElement('style');
 style.type = 'text/css';
 if (style.styleSheet)
  style.styleSheet.cssText = _cssRules;
 else
  style.innerHTML = _cssRules;
 document.head.appendChild(style);
 return wrap;
}

function addVendorPrefix(property) {
 return '-webkit-' + property +
   '-moz-' + property +
   '-o-' + property +
   property;
}

function showGeometry(elm) {
 if (elm.checked)
  document.querySelector('.sphere').classList.add('show-geometry');
 else
  document.querySelector('.sphere').classList.remove('show-geometry');
}

document.body.appendChild(createModel());
```

```css
.sphere-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-perspective: 1000px;
 -o-perspective: 1000px;
 perspective: 1000px;
}
.sphere {
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: center center -100px;
 -moz-transform-origin: center center -100px;
 -o-transform-origin: center center -100px;
 transform-origin: center center -100px;
 -webkit-animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
 -o-animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
 animation: spin 60s infinite linear;
}
.sphere div {
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 010.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {-webkit-transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
 010.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {-moz-transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
 010.00% {-o-transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {-o-transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {-o-transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {-o-transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
@keyframes spin {
 010.00% {transform: rotateX(   0deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 020.00% {transform: rotateX( 360deg) rotateY( 360deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 030.00% {transform: rotateX( 720deg) rotateY( 720deg) rotateZ(   0deg);}
 100.00% {transform: rotateX(2880deg) rotateY(3240deg) rotateZ(2520deg);}
}
input, input~ label {
 cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked~ label {
 color: #f77;
}
.show-geometry div {
 background: rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.5) !important;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
 -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
 -o-backface-visibility: visible;
 backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input id="show-geometry" type="checkbox" onchange="showGeometry(this);">
<label for="show-geometry">Show geometry</label>
```

Answer (score 7):

### Sphere like shape

**There is no actual 3D shapes in html5**
But you can stack 2D shapes on top of each other.
With this in mind you can create pretty a close representation of a sphere.

```css
.container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  //transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid pink;
}
.circ {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 5px solid firebrick;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform 2s linear;
}
.circ:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-55px);
}
.circ:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-45px);
}
.circ:nth-of-type(3) {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-25px);
}
.circ:nth-of-type(4) {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-10px);
}
.circ:nth-of-type(5) {
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(10px);
}
.circ:nth-of-type(6) {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(25px);
}
.circ:nth-of-type(7) {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(45px);
}
.circ:nth-of-type(8) {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  transform: translatex(calc(-50%)) translateY(-50%) rotateX(40deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(55px);
}
/*ANIMATION*/

.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-60px);
}
.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-40px);
}
.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(-20px);
}
.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(0px);
}
.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(20px);
}
.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(40px);
}
.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(60px);
}
.container:hover .circ:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: translatex(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateX(180deg) rotateY(40deg) translateZ(70px);
}
.container:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice! If you use trigonometric ratios to generate that, it will be even more realistic!

Answer (score 1):

```css
#cont {
  perspective: 10000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: rotat 1s linear infinite;
  animation: rotat 10s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 50%;
}
.circ {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: orange;
}
.circ:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateX(120deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateX(150deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
/*other side rotated*/

.circ:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotateY(150deg);
}
.circ:nth-child(13) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.oth {
  background: crimson;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotat {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotat {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <div class="circ"></div>
  <!--rotated other side-->
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
  <div class="circ oth"></div>
</div>
```