# Blurring the right side only of an image inside a sphere

Tags: javascript, css

I am having trouble finding a solution to something I'm working on and am in need of some education.

I have a "Vanilla" JavaScript game I've been working on that involves terraforming.  It's an idle game with resources that increase and switches to toggle the terraformer.  Once a planet has been terraformed, the "exp" goes up.  I have some HTML "inside" my JS that updates at certain points.  The img of the sphere will reflect the users exp via concatenating like this:

```
    elems6 += "<center>";
    if (exp != null) {
        elems6 += "<div id='dvLand' style='background:url(../images/dirt/" + exp + ".png);'>&nbsp;</div>";//inside the solution folder, the images are named for the appropriate level
    }
    elems6 += "<span id='buyLandX'>&otimes;</span>";
    elems6 += "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
    elems6 += "</center>";
```

note: It is important to mention that the background img is set using JS as it changes when the user upgrades.

I'm using keyframes to make the sphere rotate, BUT when the spin is complete and starts over, it doesn't look very smooth.  In fact, you can definitely tell it's just an image wrapped around a spinning div.  (see: image)

[image: screen shot of planet]

CSS:

```
#dvLand {
height:200px;
width:200px;
opacity:.5;
border-radius:50%;
animation:spin 50s ease-in-out infinite;
transform:rotate(-15deg);
position:relative;
margin-bottom:3%;
box-shadow: 0 10px 0 10px transparent inset;/*my attempt to resolve issue*/
}
#dvLand:before{
content:"";
position:absolute;
bottom:-50px;
border-radius:50%;
left:0;
height:50%;
width:100%;
background:transparent;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}
#dvLand:after{
content:"";
position:absolute;z-index:12;
top:0;left:0;height:100%;
width:100%;border-radius:50%;
box-shadow:inset -20px -20px 20px 2px #222, inset 20px 20px 20px 5px rgba(200,200,200,0.4);    
}
@-moz-keyframes spin{
to{background-position:400px 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin{
to{background-position:400px 0;}
}

@keyframes spin{
to{background-position:400px 0;}
}
```

my CSS was found in an answer in this question: [How to create a sphere in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891893/how-to-create-a-sphere-in-css) and works great for many images that load, but not all.

I'm assuming that if i can blur just a few px's on one end, that i might be able to produce a blending effect.

I have over 50 imgs that need to "blend in" and i would like to avoid going in to Photoshop and manually smudging the edges to get my desired design.  If i cannot do this with CSS and it needs to be done with JS, please ensure the code is vanilla, as i'm trying to avoid using libraries like Jquery for my own autodidactic(did i use that word right?) reasons... Thank you to anyone that can help learn me.

Comment: Blurring is not going solve it...The left and right side don't attach to each other, blurring would make the images lose all detail at the edges before the edges would attach. I would use tiled/pattern images. Making tiled/pattern images is an art on itself, there is no magical js code that makes an image tiled.

Comment: that is what i was afraid of.

Comment: Making an image repeatable isn't that hard, in your case only the x axis need to repeat. Just flip the left and right half of the image vertically and then use the patch tool or something in a photo editor to make it look like one image again instead of 2 halfes.

Comment: Or just be lazy and put a black gradient on the left and right edge of the image to make it look like the dark side of the planet.

Comment: Sometimes you can also just attach a flipped version of the image to the left or right side of the image to make kt mirror repeat itself though that would only look ok in some cases.